# Error - Using Mongoose to connect to Azure CosmosDB

Tags: node.js, database, azure, mongoose, emulation

I am trying to connect to the Microsoft Azure CosmosDB Emulator in Node.js using `mongoose`. This is the code I am using:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:8081/cryptam?ssl=true");
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
(node:6572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): #<Object>
(node:6572) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If I use this without url encoding, this is the error I get:

```
(node:8088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character
(node:8088) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So, how do I fix this error to connect to my local Azure Cosmos DB emulator using Mongoose?

Comment: API Keys are supposed to be kept secret.  Microsoft would revoke it if they knew you posted it publicly.

Comment: @ashleedawg - that's a publicly-known default key for the local emulator. Exact same key for every single install of the emulator. The emulator is a dev/test tool, and has the default key baked-in. The OP hasn't given away anything, and nobody needs to revoke anything. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) for more information about the emulator (including documented key).

Comment: @DavidMakogon - well that's good - so the mistake was when the OP referred to it as "my key" (prior to the revision).  Still, it's probably good to get into the habit of protecting all security devices.  Wouldn't be the first time passwords or keys were inadvertently shared around here...

Comment: I spent a good while trying to get it working as well with no luck. Microsoft support couldn't offer any solutions that didn't involve switch to the document client. There aren't any switches when running the emulator to use the mongo api so I think it might just be the old DocumentDb emulator renamed to Cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const mongoUri = `mongodb://${process.env.COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT}:${process.env.COSMOSDB_KEY}@${
  process.env.COSMOSDB_ACCOUNT
}.documents.azure.com:${process.env.COSMOSDB_PORT}/${process.env.COSMOSDB_DB}?ssl=true`;


// Local MongoDB Connection String
// const mongoUri = `mongodb://localhost:27017/connect-todoes`;

function connect() {
  mongoose.set('debug', true);
  return mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { useMongoClient: true });
}

module.exports = {
  connect,
  mongoose
};
```